# Copy object with function as a property in DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, devtools

When copying an object with function as a property in the chrome console, the property is lost at all. How to use `copy()` in DevTools and copy a whole property without losing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see about copying json with function property to clipboard

```
const isArrowFn = (fn) => 
  (typeof fn === 'function') &&
  !/^(?:(?:\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/\s*)|(?:\/\/[^\r\n]*))*\s*(?:(?:(?:async\s(?:(?:\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/\s*)|(?:\/\/[^\r\n]*))*\s*)?function|class)(?:\s|(?:(?:\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/\s*)|(?:\/\/[^\r\n]*))*)|(?:[_$\w][\w0-9_$]*\s*(?:\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/\s*)*\s*\())/.test(fn.toString());


copy(
  JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
      if (typeof val === "function")
        return !isArrowFn(val)
          ? val.toString().substring(
              val.toString().indexOf("{") + 1,
              val.toString().lastIndexOf("}")
            )
          : val.toString();
      return val;
    })
  )
);
```